# How do I change the Docker image installation directory?

Tags: fedora, docker

My main drive, sda, is a low capacity SSD so I would like to run my docker images on sdb as there is much more space. I have already sorted the mount point with appropriate paths, etc.

This question is about the [Docker guidance here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169).

It states in order to change the image directory to do the following.

> Fedora/Centos: edit /etc/sysconfig/docker, and add the -g option

However I have no such file.

How should I proceed, and where do I move my existing images from once I have changed this setting?

Comment: have you tried symlinking the current image directory to the mount point of /dev/sdb? 

i.e. 
ln -sf /path/to/docker/images /path/to/mounted/drive

You'll want to move all your current images to the mounted drive before doing so though

Comment: @RobotJohnny That's likely to break with SELinux without additional configuration.